# There is angular directive for "if bool cal f()"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

how can I check variable (that I get through directive) and if it's value is true - call function?

for example: I have in directive template:

```
<a href="" ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="i.exec()">
```

and I want to add something like: ng-if-true-then-call="i.foo? bar()"
so that if i.foo is true -> the function bar of the directive controller will run.
(the items var come via the configuration of the directive

```
<direct items="items">
```

and the scope is

```
scope: {
        items: '=',
}
```

I need to do new directive for this, or there is any existing tool I can use? thanks!

Comment: actually you can pass `i` to your function and do the logic in your function

Comment: Can you give us a specific example of what you are trying to do (without using names like "foo" and "bar")? I think you are on the wrong track

Answer (score 0):

your directive template:

```
<a href="" ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="exec(i)">
```

in your controller:

```
scope.exec = function (i) {
    if (i.foo) {
        bar();
    }
};
```